# search returns duplicated key error when punching in the search value faster

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am calling an apex method to return records based on a search value, and the searching happens as you type. The issue I am having is when I type in the characters slowly no error occurs and if it is punched in fast a duplicated key error occurs. What could be the reason?
Here is the apex method:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static list<sumchans__Address_Master__c> getAddresstList(string searchKey) {
    string sTempSearchKey = '%' + searchKey + '%';      
    list<sumchans__Address_Master__c> addresses = new list<sumchans__Address_Master__c>();
    for(sumchans__Address_Master__c addr : [SELECT Id,sumchans__Full_Address_Ext_Id__c,(select sumchans__Internet_Offerings__c,sumchans__Penetration__c from sumchans__ADDRESS_STATS__r ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 3) FROM sumchans__Address_Master__c WHERE sumchans__Full_Address_Ext_Id__c LIKE : sTempSearchKey LIMIT 5]){
        addresses.add(addr);
    }       
    return addresses;
}
```

Here is the HTML part:

```
<lightning-input variant="label-hidden" label="Search address:" type="search"
    onchange={handleOnInput} placeholder="Search for an address, city or postal code!">
</lightning-input>
```

Here is the call from js:

```
    handleOnInput = (event) => {
      this.debounceEvent(300, () => {
        this.searchAddressFunction(event.target.value);
      })
    }

  debounceEvent = (time, callback) => {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(()=> {
      callback();
    }, time);
  };
      searchAddressFunction(searchValue) {
        this.addresses.splice(0,this.addresses.length);
        this.showDatatable = true;
        if(searchValue !== '') {     
          getAddresstList({
            searchKey: searchValue
          }).then(result => {
            for (let i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
                switch (result[i].sumchans__ADDRESS_STATS__r.length) {
                  case 1: {
                    this.addresses.push({  
                      "key":result[i].Id,            
                      "streetAddress": result[i].sumchans__Full_Address_Ext_Id__c,
                      "units":result[i].sumchans__ADDRESS_STATS__r[0].sumchans__Total_Units__c,              "internetOfferings":result[i].sumchans__ADDRESS_STATS__r[0].sumchans__Internet_Offerings__c,          
                    });
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            })
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** - Fixed inability to add params to the call

You are not applying a rate limit to your call... so it's possible that you could be calling that Apex method many times a second. To prevent this happening, implement something like this:

```
timer = null;  

handleOnInput = (event) => {
  this.debounceEvent(300, this.searchAddressFunction.bind(null,event.target.value));
};

debounceEvent = (time, callback) => {
  clearTimeout(this.timer);
  this.timer = setTimeout(()=> {
    callback();
  }, time);
};

searchAddressFunction = (val) => {
    console.log(val);
}
```

Call the handleOnInput method from your search input, adjust the timeout (I have it at 300 ms, but you may even want to extend it out to perhaps 500ms or more.

I can't guarantee this will solve all your problems, but it's going to help and it's pretty much mandatory to do something like this for a search as you type function - otherwise at the very least you'll lock up the UI.

Comment: Thanks @Casper, Not sure what I am doing wrong, I edited the original post with the answer you put in, now I get POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @sumchans I realised that you could not pass params the way I had it set up - I've bound the target in the updated example, so your call should work properly.

Comment: Thanks @Casper, I think that worked, even with the revised code I got duplicated key error, then I increased the timeout to 500. SO far it is working good. I am guessing it will work without errors.